# Is there a way to turn a DataFrame/correlation matrix into a DataFrame with one column per cell combination?

Tags: r, matrix, transform

I have a data frame that is 89x89 that I've turned into a correlation matrix using cor(). My question is if there is a way to turn each column-row pairing into its own column in a new data.frame that would have one row and all possible combinations of row-column pairs, each as its own column. For example:

```
    [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
[1]  a   b   c   d   e
[2]  f   a   g   h   i
[3]  j   k   a   l   m
[4]  n   o   p   a   q
[5]  r   s   t   u   a
```

would turn into

```
[1][1] [1][2] [1][3] [1][4] [1][5] [2][1] [2][2] [2][3] [2][4] 
   a      f      j      n      r      b      a      k     o
```

and so on for the entire matrix, with [1][1] being the first column header and so on.

So far, I haven't been able to find a solution that does this. I've found solutions that turn each entry into its own row in a DataFrame, e.g.,

```
     col1 col2 col3
row1 [1]   [1]   a
row2 [1]   [2]   f
row3 [1]   [3]   j
```

which isn't exactly what I am looking for.

Hopefully I am overlooking a simple solution. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You want `pivot_wider`. But to help you, please provide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column names containing `[` and `]` are problematic, so I've used a slightly different naming convention to yours, but I believe this gives you the structure you want.

First generate some test data

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(
       a=c(1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6),
       b=c(0.2, 1, 0.2, 0.4),
       c=c(0.4, 0.2, 1, 0.2),
       d=c(0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 1)
     )
d
# A tibble: 4 × 4
      a     b     c     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   1     0.2   0.4   0.6
2   0.2   1     0.2   0.4
3   0.4   0.2   1     0.2
4   0.6   0.4   0.2   1
```

Then do what you want

```
d %>% 
  mutate(row=letters[1:nrow(.)]) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-row) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from=c(row, name),
    values_from=value
  )
    a_a   a_b   a_c   a_d   b_a   b_b   b_c   b_d   c_a   c_b   c_c   c_d   d_a   d_b   d_c   d_d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   0.2   0.4   0.6   0.2     1   0.2   0.4   0.4   0.2     1   0.2   0.6   0.4   0.2     1
```

**Edit**

```
d %>% 
  mutate(row=letters[1:nrow(.)]) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from=row,
    values_from=-row
  )
```

Gives the same result and is slightly shorter.